# Prevent VSCode to CRLF files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Windows device within a team using MacOS and Linux or WSL.

I've set my Eol settings to LF to match the configuration of my teammates, but every time I checkout to another branch or discard changes from git, some files always end up converted to CRLF.
I then have to manually reset that file to LF, or run a `lint --fix`, then `git add --renormalize .` to clean my git status.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening ?

Comment: Check if your `core.autocrlf` [config setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreautocrlf) is set to `true` with `git config --get core.autocrlf`

Comment: Forgot to mention that. It is set to false.

Comment: So `git config core.autocrlf true` should be your solution. It'll ask git to checkout files from the repo and make them go LF->CRLF for you to be able to use them on your windows system, BUT when you add/commit, git will (transparently) turn them back CRLF->LF so they remain LF in the repo.

Comment: Don't use `core.autocrlf`.  Use `.gitattributes` instead.  Otherwise the next team member with a Windows machine will have a problem.

Comment: And which settings in gitattributes would do the trick ?

Comment: `autocrlf` is not a solution, because it only applies to the local machine. We are trying to fix the project for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`* text=auto eol=lf` in .gitattributes did the trick.

Comment: where is the .gitattributes located? is it in user's home?

Comment: @AkshayHiremath the .gitatributes file is a non mandatory file that can be added to any git repository, usually at the root of your file structure.